# Using HTMX/Javascript in Django Template : not defined

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, htmx

I decided to try HTMX with Django and implementing a Django form in a modal box. I found [this tutorial](https://blog.benoitblanchon.fr/django-htmx-modal-form/) and was following it.

I got to the part where it uses an HTMX function `htmx:afterSwap` to open the modal but when I put that in a script tag in the template, I run into an error. It is Step 4 where the error occurs.

My template looks (mostly) like this. I've tried to trim it down to the essentials.

```
{% for thing in things %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
    <ul id="myThingList" class="things">
    {% endif %}
    <button id="thing{{ thing.id }}Button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" hx-get="{% url 'myapp:things-create' %}" hx-target="#thingSection"> Upload Thing</button>
    <li id="thingItem" class="thing" hx-target="this" hx-swap="outerHTML">
        {{ thing.name }}
    </li>
    <div id="thingModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="thingModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div id="thingSection" class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" hx-target="this" role="document"></div>
    </div>
    {% if forloop.last %}
    </ul>
    {% endif  %}
{% empty %}
    <p class="no-things">No things have been added yet.</p>
{% endfor %}


<script>
const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("thingModal"))

htmx.on("htmx:afterSwap", (e) => {
  // Response targeting #thingSection => show the modal
  if (e.detail.target.id == "thingSection") {
    modal.show()
  }
})

</script>
```

I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined`

Additional information:

HTMX works (I use it in other parts of the template without issue) and Bootstrap is loaded because all the CSS works on the page/templates, too.

I use webpack to vendor in all my JS files (combined/minimized) them into one `vendors.h3117haj3.js` file. The numbers are a random hash that is linked to in a base template that I extend in other templates.

Is there a way to get it to recognize `bootstrap` and `htmx` in that script tag?

The `index.js` file looks like this:

```
import "../scss/myapp.scss";
import "../css/style.css";
import 'htmx.org';
import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: Could you also share the `main.js` file, where you import all your JS dependencies?

Comment: @Dauros I have added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using a bundler you have the option](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/webpack/#import-bootstrap) to include all Boostrap components under a namespace like `bootstrap`, or you can include only individual components to keep the bundle size small. The referenced tutorial used the script include method that by default includes all BS components under the `bootstrap` namespace. To replicate it with a bundler, you have to modify your `index.js`:

```
import "../scss/myapp.scss"
import "../css/style.css"
import 'htmx.org'

// Import all of Bootstrap's JS
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
```

Then `bootstrap.Modal()` will be a valid function.

If you want to import only the modal component, you can use:

```
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap'
```

Then you have the `Modal()` method available, so you need to modify this line in your template as well:

```
const modal = new Modal(document.getElementById("thingModal"))
```